# carthage build not works with Xcode 12.0, It works fine with Xcode 11.3. Task failed with exit code 1:

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

apple@Apples-iMac ConfigData % carthage build --no-skip-current

Please update to the latest Carthage version: 0.36.0. You currently are on 0.35.0

*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/y2/9rgqlp3n51nd73tg8_7gf7nr0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.hHyZ7t.log

*** Building scheme "ConfigData" in ConfigData.xcodeproj
Build Failed

```
Task failed with exit code 1:
/usr/bin/xcrun lipo -create /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConfigData-bypjmncfuigbwmaixccfdcxuhgpp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ConfigData/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/ConfigData.framework/ConfigData /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConfigData-bypjmncfuigbwmaixccfdcxuhgpp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/ConfigData.framework/ConfigData -output /Users/apple/Desktop/XCode_12/ConfigData/Carthage/Build/iOS/ConfigData.framework/ConfigData
```

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/y2/9rgqlp3n51nd73tg8_7gf7nr0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.hHyZ7t.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carthage is working on these issues. In the meantime try this workaround.

https://gist.github.com/skymobilebuilds/61f4a95bd62a3db36b52719aeab7e0d5

This has worked for me.